# Regex URL pattern except specific subsite

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a webcrawler, where I am trying to make a regex to support the following.

Match: all pages starting with

```
   http://intranet/
```

But not starting with

```
    http://intranet/sites/ and http://intranet/search/
```

And in the subfolder
/Pages/
Ending with
.aspx

```
Valid sample: 
http://intranet/products/Pages/default.aspx
Invalid samples:
http://intranet/Pages/sofus/default.aspx
http://intranet/sites/products/Pages/default.aspx
http://intranet/products/Pages/default.aspx#
```

So far I have made this

```
 ^http://intranet.*/Pages/.*.aspx+
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can `/Pages` be any deeper then one level below `intranet`?  Also, are there 2 positive conditions here:  1. Match anything `intranet/` that is NOT `/sites` or `/search` 2. Match things in `/Pages` ONLY if they end in `.aspx`.  So with 2., would like... `http://intranet/example/x/y/z` work, or should that be invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^http://intranet/(?!sites|search)[^/]+/Pages/.*\.aspx$
```

The `(?!...)` creates what's known as a [*negative lookahead assertion*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion) and ensure that the `[^/]+` does not start with `sites` or `search`.

Here's a [demonstration](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Ehttp://intranet/%28?!sites%7Csearch%29%5B%5E/%5D%2b/Pages/.%2a%5C.aspx%24&input=http://intranet/products/Pages/default.aspx%0A%0Ahttp://intranet/Pages/sofus/default.aspx%0Ahttp://intranet/sites/products/Pages/default.aspx%0Ahttp://intranet/products/Pages/default.aspx#).

Comment: Nice Regex! I always forget about the lookahead/lookbehind assertions!

Comment: Absolutely great! Thanks.